# Incorrect output with double for loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I'm splitting strings into n-grams using the nltk but I am struggling to get the correct output.

Here is an example of the string:

`'F++FF-++FF-+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-+FF-F+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-+FF-F++FF-+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-+FF-F+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-+FF-F+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-+FF-F+FF-F++FF-+FF-F++FF-+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-+FF-F+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-+FF-F+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-+FF-F++FF-+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-+FF-F+FF-F++FF-++FF-+FF-F+FF-F++FF-+FF-F++FF-++FF-+FF-F++FF-++FF-++FF-++FF-'`

The idea is to do rolling n-grams of 2, 3, 4 and 5 characters respectively and nest them into one list like so:
`[[2-grams], [3-grams], [4-grams], [5-grams]]`

So for the above list it would be:

```
[['F+', '+F', 'F-', '++', 'FF', '-+', 'FF', ...], 
['F++', 'FF-', '++F', 'F-+', 'FF-', ...], 
['F++F', 'F-++', 'FF-+', 'FF-F', ...],  
['F++FF', '-++FF', '-+FF-', ...]]
```

I'm using a dataframe to store everything and trying to accomplish the above like so:

```
allData['Rolling n-grams'] = allData['L-string'].apply(
    lambda x: [(''.join(tup)) for i in range(2, 6)
                    for tup in list(ngrams(list(x), i))]
)
```

But this dumps all the n-grams into one long list
P.S. The `''.join(tup)` is required because the ngrams function outputs the characters pairs into tuples like `[('F','+'), ('+', 'F'), ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify how I ended up using [yatu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56663563/7167076)'s answer:

```
ngram_list = allData['L-string'].apply(lambda x: ((''.join(tup)) for i in range(2, 6) for tup in list(ngrams(list(x), i))))

gram = []
for ngram in ngram_list:
    tmp = [[*v] for _, v in groupby(sorted(ngram, key=len), key=len)]
    gram.append(tmp)

allData['Rolling n-grams'] = gram
```